# How to improve/optimize speed of MongoDB query?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a small Mongo database with ~30k records. 
Simple query, which uses 5-6 parameters takes almost a second (considering entire DB is in RAM).
Can anyone suggest what I'm doing wrong?

> 2015-11-26T18:41:29.540+0200 [conn3] command vvpilotdb2.$cmd command:
>   count { count: "TestResults", query: { Test: 5.0, IsAC: true,
>   InputMode: 0.0, IsOfficialTest: true, IsSanity: false, IsStress:
>   false, IsUnderNoise: false, MetalRodSize: 9.0 }, fields: {} }
>   planSummary: COLLSCAN keyUpdates:0 numYields:1 locks(micros) r:1397227
>   reslen:48 944ms

Here is db.stats(). I haven't assigned any indexes by myself. all settings - default.:

```
> db.stats()
{
        "db" : "vvpilotdb2",
        "collections" : 5,
        "objects" : 28997,
        "avgObjSize" : 7549.571610856296,
        "dataSize" : 218914928,
        "storageSize" : 243347456,
        "numExtents" : 17,
        "indexes" : 3,
        "indexSize" : 964768,
        "fileSize" : 469762048,
        "nsSizeMB" : 16,
        "dataFileVersion" : {
                "major" : 4,
                "minor" : 5
        },
        "extentFreeList" : {
                "num" : 0,
                "totalSize" : 0
        },
        "ok" : 1
}
```

Comment: What's the explain of that query? Are you missing some indexes?

Comment: Can you please run the explain in pretty mode? Its impossible to read that long line. That being said, the answer to optimization in Mongo is almost always (1) correct indexing and (2) sharding

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to Mongo. I didn't know that explain query meant, I googled it up, here is explain of the query I'm running (I'm using 32-bit mongo 2.6 on my old Win7 machine. Here query runs >2x times faster ~400ms. Don't know why.  `"cursor" : "BasicCursor",
 "isMultiKey" : false,
 "n" : 30,
 "nscannedObjects" : 27772,
 "nscanned" : 27772,
 "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 27772,
 "nscannedAllPlans" : 27772,
 "scanAndOrder" : false,
 "indexOnly" : false,
 "nYields" : 216,
 "nChunkSkips" : 0,
 "millis" : 380,
 "server" : "mike-PC:27017",
 "filterSet" : false`

Comment: Also, I haven't assigned any indexes, Should I assign them?  to what fields?

Comment: Add `.explain()`  after the query `find()` to see what's going on with the query. Also, create some indexes on the fields you are using in the query, that should speed things up.

Answer (score 2):

In `MongoDB`, the `_id` field is indexed by default.

You should index the field which you will be using for making the query.
Compound indexes can also be created on multiple fields and the order for them (ascending/descending).

Here's the documentation for the same:

https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/indexes/